# Open web page with custom cookies in Python

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2

For example, I have cookies

```
my_cookies = {'name': 'Albert', 'uid': '654897897564'}
```

and I want to open page http://website.com

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor())
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible)'))
opener.open('http://website.com').read()
```

How I can do this with my predefined cookies ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need a few more steps:

```
import urllib2
import cookielib

cp = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
cj = cp.cookiejar

# see cookielib.Cookie documentation for options description
cj.set_cookie(cookielib.Cookie(0, 'a_cookie', 'a_value',
                               '80', False, 'domain', True, False, '/path',
                               True, False, None, False, None, None, None))
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler(),
                              cp)
opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible)'))
opener.open('http://website.com').read()
```